# AWS S3: Image resize using lambda in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, laravel-5.3

Currently my image upload system in Laravel 5.3  works like this way.

1.User uploads the image.

2.Resize the image using imagick library.

3.store the original and the cropped image in AWS S3.

This works fine now i would like to move second step(Image resize) with AWS lambda but i can't find anything about AWS lambda integration with php
however node-js and java integration guides are available in official documentation.

So there is any other services (other than aws lambda) avaliable to achieve my functionality??

Comment: Hey @Jabaa, I want to resize the images after they are already in the bucket. Do you have any good solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP, or any other language for that matter, on AWS Lambda, but you need to encapsulate it within a NodeJS wrapper.

Luckily, AWS provides an official, very straightforward guide on how to do this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/

Furthermore, if you want to save some time (by not manually building a PHP distribution as explained in the aforementioned article), you can use the following Docker container: https://github.com/dannylinden/aws-lambda-php

Answer (score -1):

Currently AWS lambda functions are not supporting php, As you are a PHP developer you can easily write nodeJS script for Image re-size functionality. Max it will come 12 to 15 lines. lots of examples are also available for the same functionality. S3 to auto trigger configuration you can do to lambda functions. So your work will be very minimal.

But still if you are looking for any alternative solution, you have to use ec2 instance, there you have to expose one REST API. that API should be able to receive the image and re-size it, finally store that original and re-sized images to two different AWS s3 buckets (but not recommend).

If you want to directly store into s3 bucket from application (php) it self, then write the code for re-sizing and store in tow separate buckets from your application.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac please explain your answer

Comment: @kamal Gadepalli i didn't get the meaning of this `As you are a PHP developer you can easily write nodeJS script for Image re-size functionality`

Comment: @Jabaa I believe it means that if you know how to write PHP, then you should not find it difficult to write javascript for node.  They are syntactically similar enough that it should not be intimidating to switch between them.

Comment: @KamalGadepalli it's true, if you can make it binary compatible and package it up to run on the [standard Lambda AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html), then you can run it in Lambda for Node using a simple node wrapper to [spawn a child process](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/)

Comment: I don't have such greater experience in node js

Comment: Hi @NinoSkopac i have not find any direct way to use php in AWS lambda functions. if you are confident on that can you please suggest any example.

Comment: @KamalGadepalli I've done it myself using the example in the guide I've provider. The crucial part is bridging the gap between Node and PHP, and for that, refer to `Creating the Lambda package` part of the guide.